# Designing M.2 socket for SSD

Tags: pcie, ssd, m2

I'm designing a *card adaptor* which converts from M.2 Key E type to M.2 Key M type (to insert an NVMe SSD into a port designed originally for Wifi cards).

I found some [reference design](https://www.congatec.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Documents/Application_Notes/AN43_M.2_Pinout_Descriptions_and_Reference_Designs.pdf) for the M.2 KeyM socket:

[image]

MY questions:

1. If I only wish to use this converter for NVMe SSD (PCIe), **can I leave open `PEDET` (pin 69)**, or pullup is required?
2. If my design will only connect pins from keyE to this keyM socket, **are C[317..343] needed** or can be left out?

Reason for these questions: I earlier used a [design](https://github.com/CRImier/MyKiCad/tree/master/Laptop%20mods/nvme_ae_to_m) made by CRImier (thank you):

[image]

And it doesn't use any single pullup-resistor or capacitor (while it still works as intended).

Moreover, the repo's [history](https://github.com/CRImier/MyKiCad/commits/master/Laptop%20mods/nvme_ae_to_m) contains a [commit](https://github.com/CRImier/MyKiCad/commit/e81c47cc09f87c9efea35013d5e15ab7a89267df):

> nvme_ae_to_m: v2, fixed tx/rx pair swaps, **removed caps**

So author used capacitors, but eventually he decided to remove those for some unknown reason.

Comment: What would your adapter do better than the one you already tried? The Key  E does not support SATA, and it is an outpuy from SSD to put M2 socket from SATA to PCIE mode, it is rather irrelevant. And the bypass caps seem necessary as bypass caps. But there is no info which caps were removed, PCIe lane caps or bypass caps or what.

Comment: I need some more parts on it (microcontrollers, etc), it's not part of the question to discuss, I wish to focus mainly for the topic described. I know keyE doesn't support SATA. Thx for `/PEDET` explain, I thought it's for signalling something to SSD and from SSD. Removed caps were between `+3.3V` and `GND`.

Comment: Shouldn't bypass caps provided by manufacturer of SSD on SSD's PCB itself? What's the reason behind putting bypass-caps onto a socket?

Answer (score 1):

1. The PEDET should be irrelevant. It is pulled up by host and it selects between SATA and PCIe mode in Key M based on insertion of SATA or PCIe card. Since your board is Key M host you could pull it up, but if you don't do anything with that info, you might as well skip it.

But technically your board allows attaching a SATA device to Key M socket and Key E socket has no support for SATA, so SATA won't work.

2. The capacitors may be important. Especially if you have devices onboard the adaptor module. It would be best to not leave them out. Surely the SSD would have it's own bypass caps, and the motherboard, but generally those two are directly connected together, and if your board does not have bypass caps, then there are longer wiring through two connectors and the PCB, so there is more inductance. Now will it matter is another question, but it is difficult to say if they are mandatory for operation, or what problems you might encounter if they are not there. Their purpose is to provide current to SSD when it needs it, and provide it quickly when it needs it. Any resistance will cause voltage drop and any inductance will cause initial voltage drop as the current is not available quickly.

Comment: I agree with all. I'm planning to add bypass-caps to *all* other components on the adapter board, but these caps are best to place *as-close-as-possible* to the active component (i.e. to microcontroller, or SSD on its own board), IMHO.